# Sample size for non-Inferiority Tests for Two Survival Curves Using Cox’s Proportional Hazards, parameter specification of actual hazard ratio

Tags: sample-size, cox-model, non-inferiority

I am looking into at trying to understand the parameter, "Actual Hazard Ratio", used in the following sample size calculation.

Example 1 in the following pdf.
https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Non-Inferiority_Tests_for_Two_Survival_Curves_Using_Coxs_Proportional_Hazards_Model.pdf

The manual states:
"Specify one or more hazard ratios, HR1, at which the power is calculated. HR is defined as the treatment hazard rate (h2) divided by the control hazard rate (h1). HR1 represents the assumed value at which the power of rejecting H0 is calculated. In non-inferiority tests, this ratio is usually assumed to be 1.0".

Yet I cannot really figure out why one would want to specify several of these "Actual hazard rate":s?

This example is easily replicable in the R-program TrialSize (if one assumes a total event probability of 0.4).

```r
library(TrialSize)

Cox.NIS(alpha=0.025, beta=0.1,
        loghr=log(seq(0.5,1, by=0.1)), 
        p1=0.5, 
        d=0.4, 
        delta=log(1.2))
```

My question is which I cannot seem to see a clear answer in the documentation. How would you determine the correct value for "Actual Hazard Ratio" (or loghr TrialSize) in the example given? Is it based on previous historical data?